# Codeigniter: calling model from view - DB content seems frozen

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, postgresql

I am trying to use javascript in my CI view to update (without refresh) a data model every 2 seconds, for my use case where the database contents can be changed by other users.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var refreshFunc = setInterval(function() {
    <?php 
    $this -> load -> model('m_cube', '', TRUE);
    $stamp = $this -> $m_cube -> stamp();
    ?>
    var stamp = "<?php echo $stamp; ?>";
    console.log(stamp);             
    }, 2000);
    refreshFunc;
    </script>
```

I am using JS `setInterval` to create the 2 second loop, and calling the CI model to retrieve data from the Postgresql database. In the simplified code sample, it's just asking the DB for a timestamp. The problem is that the timestamp written to console doesn't update - something is stuck.

```
2013-10-21 14:35:54.168-04 
2013-10-21 14:35:54.168-04 
2013-10-21 14:35:54.168-04 
...
```

Same behavior when querying a table of real data - it doesn't return up-to-date values.

Why does the model access a "frozen" version of the DB?

Answer (score 2):

It's not stuck or "frozen", it's that you had a bit of confusion on what comes before and what after.

I don't see you using AJAX, so by the time your php has been processed (i.e, the data fetched from the db and assigned to $stamp) the page - html, css and javascript too - are yet to be generated and served by the server, nor outputted by the browser.

This means that inside your setInterval you always have the same value, which has been already generated, and thus you keep reprinting the same string.

If you want a continue update, you need to keep requesting the data to the server, and that's where AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) can be handy since it runs as a separate request from the main one, so you can work on two different "levels" and fetch content while the rest of the page remains static (already served and outputted).

If you're using jQUery you can look into [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which makes this kind of things pretty easy.

Comment: ah yes. time to brush up on my  ajax

Answer (score 0):

When this script runs at the server it fetches the model data and replace the `<?php ?>` tags with the results. So when it comes to client browser, it doesn't contact server every 2 seconds, but logs the `stamp` value every 2 seconds. If you want it to be updated you should consider using **Ajax** technology.